# Blender crashes on minimise and maximise

Tags: rendering

Blender opens without a problem but when I minimize and reclick it, it crashes. When I look up for error code from console I get this:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Can't find a recent bug report involving minimize and the output looks fine as well. Are you using the current release version of Blender 2.8? If yes, I think you may want to take this to the official bug tracker. You can create a bug report either through Blender in *Help > Report a Bug* or https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/ Please add your system information to the bug report which can be saved in *Help > Save System Info*.

Comment: Hi. A tip: from the terminal select and  copy text, then paste it here, easier than using image.  For the time being don't minimize blender, lol.